# Symfony bhLDAPAuthPlugin redirect issue

Tags: authentication, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

i'm having troubles with the `bhLDAPAuthPlugin` for symfony when the user session expires. It redirects to the signin form as expected but once the user is authenticated, instead of redirect him to the requested page (the one witch first requested the user), it redirects him to the requested page adding exra information to the URL.

Let me show it to you with an example:
The user is in this URL and the session expires
`myapp/editSomething/id/231`

And then is redirected by the `bhLDAPAuthPlugin` to the signin form. Once the user had entered the username & password is redirected here
`myapp/editSomething/images/loadingAnimation.gif`

I dont know what loadingAnimation.gif is (is not in my /images/ directory nor in anywhere else of my app), nor where is this additional information added :S

Could you please help me to find the place where i must change this behaviour?

Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing is done in the action. The redirect url is build [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/bhLDAPAuthPlugin/trunk/modules/bhLDAPAuth/actions/actions.class.php#L56):

```
// always redirect to a URL set in app.yml
// or to the referer
// or to the homepage
$signinUrl = sfConfig::get('app_sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url', $user->getReferer('@homepage'));
```

Did you define something in your `app.yml` for `app_sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url` ?

```
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    success_signin_url: @my_route?param=value # the plugin uses the referer as default
```

So it seems that your referer is bad. Try to define an url in the app.yml to see if the behavior is different.

Comment: i can't find the `app.yml` file. Is in the bhLDAP plugin folder or in the app's /config/ directory? Thanks

Comment: The app.yml is in your app directory: /apps/[your_app]/config/app.yml

Comment: setting the `success_signin_url` config parameter to `@homepage` redirects to the homepage. This is acceptable but i'd prefer to redirect to the requested url. Do you know how could i do that?

Comment: Try to var_dump the getReferer inside the actions, to see if there is this `loadingAnimation`. I do not have other solution ..